# sql server get last previous date excluding weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to get last previsous date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE
CAST(MyTable.DATE AS DATE) = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

I want to exclude weekends and from today should give yesterday, or on Monday, will give the previous Friday

Comment: Recommend reading: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734)

Comment: *"I want to exclude weekends and from today should give yesterday"* But today is a Monday, so yesterday was Sunday, which is part of the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for today being 'Monday' and subtract 3 days, otherwise subtract 1:

```
SELECT DATEADD(
    day,
    IIF(DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'Monday', -3, -1),
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
```